# How to solve of race condition

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a test class consisting of 2 fields and one method.

```
private final Lock firstLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
private final Lock secondLock = new ReentrantLock(true);

public void method() {
        firstLock.lock();
        try {
            // data transfer to the server
        } finally {
            firstLock.unlock();
        }
// race condition
        secondLock.lock();
        try {
            // read response from server
        } finally {
            secondLock.unlock();
        }
}
```

I have as 2 questions:

1. This method is susceptible to the "Race condition" situation? (for one object, different threads will call this method, It is necessary for me that **the thread that acquired the first lock was the first to acquired the second lock**). Probably it was a rhetorical question.
2. How to avoid it? (I do not consider calling `secondLock.lock()` before `firstLock.unlock()`, because my task is to create independent locks (the first lock will also be used in another the method and should not depend on the second lock)).

---

Added

```
public void method2() {
        firstLock.lock();
        try {
            // data transfer to the server (without waiting for a response from it)
        } finally {
            firstLock.unlock();
        }
}
```

Comment: If that is really what you want, why don't you just define and acquire a third lock around both, local to just that method?

Comment: Without seeing what other parties are using those locks, the whole code is irrelevant and could be replaced with a `synchronized` method instead of doing such silly locking.

Comment: Seems like you are mixing up "race condition" and "deadlock". Your locking strategy cannot lead to deadlocks (locks are acquired in the same order by all threads). To say anything about race conditions (or "thread safety" if you wish) one must see the actual code.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the answer! I made changes to my question for greater clarity.

Comment: @PontusGagge Thanks for the answer! Using a third lock is a good idea, but this will affect the overall data transfer rate.

Comment: Before talking about `race condition`, I think you need to post your detailed  requirements. Is it acceptable for you **data transfer to the server** and **read response from server** at same time?

Comment: It's hard to say if you have a race condition or not here. A race condition is any situation where the result is determined by the timing/ordering of the operations - bad timings or orderings can result in corrupted data, bugs etc. Just having two locks is not a cause for alarm. It depends on what the locks actually do, what data the threads operate on, and which other threads operate on that data. So you need to provide a bunch more details about that. Otherwise we can't really say. For example, if neither lock protects any shared data there's nothing to worry about, no?

Comment: @HoriaComan Thanks for the answer! To find possible errors, i must assume that no actions inside the lock block are executed.

Comment: @rmssystem what do you mean by "no actions inside the lock  block are executed"?

Comment: @HoriaComan I apologize for the bad english. I meant that the code inside the block firstLock or secondLock is not defined in advance. It can be performed very quickly and this can be neglected. (that is, assume that there is nothing inside the blocks)

Comment: Re, "my task is to create independent locks."  Creating locks is never a good thing.  At best, it sometimes is a _necessary_ thing.  Locks impair the performance of a program.  If you want a multithreaded program to perform well, then your task usually is to figure out a way to structure it so that it gives correct results while using as little locking as possible.  IMO, you need to better explain why the two locks are necessary, and you need to show more of the details of what `method()` and `method2()` actually do before anybody can give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: Maybe you could lock the second lock before unlocking the first.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. You have marked potentially "Race condition" place.
   This situation is possible if several threads will try to access to some shared resource in commented code section.
2. It is imposible with using two locks

   > It is necessary for me that the thread that acquired the first lock was the first to acquired the second lock

In other words, you want create two **dependent locks**, but:

> my task is to create **independent locks**

Comment: what makes that place to be a potential race condition?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not know all the mechanisms of multithreaded programming, but I can solve this problem by using some list of threads and the verification method Lock.hasQueuedThread(Thread thread); But it's too complicated.